# What does 'be' refer to in <java-project-name>-<version>-be.jar?

Tags: java, jar, naming

I have seen a number of java projects where, similar to 'xxxx-sources.jar' (which obviously contains source files) there is a jar ending in 'be.jar'. These seem to be similar to the full project jar less any xml config and other non-class files.

What does 'be' stand for?

Comment: I doubt if there is any standard for such a thing. In an organization, maybe. Global, unlikely.

Comment: Any concrete example?

Comment: I've definitely seen it in open source before, am checking out jakarta now. But currently in private commercial settings.

Comment: Even though there are some default naming templates in most build systems (maven, ivy, gradle) you are able to name your jar as you want. Also you can set your naming strategy in your build system as you want, however you risk it is not understoodable for others.

Comment: I understand that, but the 'be' is definitely a convention of somesort and I want to understand why it deserves a separate jar (with a subset of the project content as described)?

Comment: Any concrete example?

Comment: Perhaps "-be" stands for Belgium.  But without some really examples, we can only guess.  This is not a convention I've observed / noticed before.